# Structuring calls to update global and local state

Tags: javascript, api, service, structure, vue.js

Some of my components doesn't want to store all state globally. Two examples:

- `messages` component: usermessages are fetched and stored locally because they are only needed for the current component. But when they could not be fetched (api error), the error should be dispatched to global state (vuex).
- `buy` component: 'recent buys' are fetched and stored locally, but 'money' should be dispatched to global state, and error too when recent buys could not be fetched.

I'm currently figuring out how to structure this and I need some help. I have a directory `services` which includes calls to my api. Let's take the buy service as an example:

**/services/buy.js:**

```
// here code to dispatch money state
// here code to dispatch 'last activity' state

Vue.$http.get('/buy', credentials)
  .then((response) => {
    // return recent buys
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // here code to dispatch error state
  });
```

There are some logics between the services as well: For example, after a succesful buy, a new message should be sent from **/services/newMessage.js**

But how and where should I structure all of this? Let's take the `buy` component as an example. I see a couple of options:

**#1:** *This is the code above*

- The buy-component imports the buy service and calls it: `newBuy()`
- The service dispatches the money to global store, and the service gets the recent buys and returns them
- Back in the component, it updates the local store with the returned value from the service
- The component has the logic too: after a succesful return, it calls the message service to send a new message: `sendMessage()`

**#2:** *The difference with #1 is that the logic takes place inside the service*

- The component imports the buy service and calls it: `newBuy()`
- The service dispatches the money to global store, and imports the message service
- The message service sends a new message: `sendMessage()`
- Back to the buy service, the recent buys are fetched and returned.
- The component now updates the local store with the returned value

**#3:** *The difference with steps above is that all actions related to Vuex are inside a special actions.js file, so it is a clear separation of global and local state updates.*

- The component imports the buy service and calls it: `newBuy()`
- The service imports **./store/actions.js** and calls the `updateMoney()` service which updates the money
- Goes further with the steps from #1 or #2

Could someone please help me out? How to combine components that use both global and local state? Are one of the three steps above the right way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, based on your situation: **option 2**

For me if there is no need for a state to be shared globally then all you are doing is polluting vuex's states by writing everything to it.

If for instance you had 10 components that functioned like the buy component, and each of those pulled an individual state only they needed from your vuex store, then you will be making the vuex store harder to reason about.

Furthermore if you start attaching actions and mutations for those states, then you'll likely need to build modules for each of the 10 components, again obscuring  your state and logic.

Therefore in this instance option 2 seems a far better way to go **if you are sure you won't need the state you retrieve elsewhere**. You seem to have a pretty good grasp on why you would use vuex so that puts you in good stead. I would say that half the work with larger applications is in the planning. Therefore if you can map out how your app will function and see before you build where the connections need to be, and in turn where a components data is completely isolated, you should be able to quickly make those decisions on what you do and don't push to vuex.

In terms of the choice between option 1 & 2 I would say this again comes down to a question of scope and keeping things DRY. If every time you are returned data from `newBuy` you have to call `sendMessage` and you have the data in `buy-service` to populate the message, then your services should work together. It's fine that they do so, after all you are no doubt writing the `message-service` in a manner that decouples it from any dependancies outside those for sending messages. Therefore if the `buy-service` is written in a similar fashion it can pull that in and utilise it.

With the above in mind Option 1 therefore appears to be duplicating a function which would need to be run every time the buy service is called. For that reason I would avoid it in case in the future you want to expand things, as your app should be far easier to reason about if dependant functions are not replicated in various places. Instead you would look at `newBuy` and see on it receiving its data, it calls `sendMessage` and therefore updating is simple and the logic is clear.

---

To provide a little more context, I'd look to run the various stages like below:

- The **component** imports the **buy service** and calls: `newBuy()`

  - Calling `newBuy()` should return a *Promise* to the **component**
- The **buy service** imports the **message service**
- The **buy service** fetches the data, i.e. `newBuy` calls `getMoney` and `getRecentBuys`.

  - Both of the above return a *Promise*, now you use *Promise.all* to wait for the 2 endpoints to resolve and pass back their data.

**On resolving of the `newBuy` *Promise.all*:**

- `getMoney` returned data: the **buy service** dispatches the money to vuex modules store

  - The money store could be held within a vuex module if you have various types of data within this store. It would help make its state, actions etc.. easier to work with
- The **buy service** calls the **message service** to send a new message: `sendMessage()`
- The **buy service** resolves its *Promise*

  - pass the recent buys as the payload
- *Promise* is resolved on the **component** which now updates its local data with the payload

**On rejecting of the `newBuy` *Promise.all*:**

- The **buy service** rejects its *Promise*

  - pass an empty payload or message
  - dispatch error to vuex store
- *Promise* is rejected  on the **component** so component knows not to update its local data

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you very much. So I shouldn't make a special file in the Vuex directory `/vuex/actions.js` where actions related to Vuex are stored? For example a `setError` action that dispatches the error? Just dispatch all from my `services` directory?

Comment: By all means you can have an `actions.js` although I would probably look instead to contain them within a module, i.e. `vuex/errors.js` and that errors module has a `setError` action. This should again help to make things clearer by containing all related global actions / states etc.. within vuex modules. As above you can then call that action `store.dispatch('setError', payload)` from within your **buy service** in the event of rejection of your `newbuy` Promise.

Comment: One of the great things about Promises is how you can process a number of different requests / call various methods, before you resolve or reject them. Therefore your **component** which called the Promise doesn't need to know any of this is happening, all it cares about is whether its Promise is resolved and it can store the data, or rejected and it can't